# How to display product associated categories & filter product by categories in admin panel

Tags: product, adminhtml, catalog, product-list, grid

I am not so much familiar with magento development.i am facing some trouble
my problem is i have add **product's associated categories** within product name column in admin panel(catalog > manage products) & i have also **filter product by categories** and i don't have any idea.how to do this task.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: have you done any thing yet. share the code you tried so far?

Comment: @QaisarSatti no i don't have any idea & i am just searching & studying for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` in your custom module 
or put this file into `local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product`.

1) In `_prepareColumns` method add the following code:

```
$this->addColumn(
    'category_id',
    array(
        'header'                    => $this->__('Category'),
        'width'                     => '100px',
        'index'                     => 'category_ids',
        'type'                      => 'options',
        'options'                   => $this->getCategoryOptions(),
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_callbackCategoryFilter'),
        'renderer'                  => '***custom_module***/adminhtml_catalog_product_render_category'
    )
);
```

2) Create here in class your custom method

```
public function getCategoryOptions()
{
    $option_array = array();
    $category_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
        ->addNameToResult()
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
    foreach ($category_collection as $category) {
        if ($category->getId() > 1 && $category->getName() != 'Root Catalog') {
            $option_array[$category->getId()] = $category->getName();
        }
    }
    return $option_array;
}
```

Or, which is preferable, create this method in your custom helper.

3) Create here in class protected method `_callbackCategoryFilter`

```
protected function _callbackCategoryFilter($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return null;
    }
    $collection->joinField(
        'category_id',
        'catalog/category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id = entity_id',
        '{{table}}.category_id=' . $column->getFilter()->getValue(),
        'inner'
    );
}
```

4) Create renderer:

```
class ***Company_Module***_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Render_Category
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $productCategories = array();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getData('entity_id'));
        $categories = $product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            array_push($productCategories, $category->getName());
        }
        return implode('<br>', $productCategories);
    }
}
```

The result:
[image: The result]

Comment: This Works Fine but there is a problem of page load time, this render function increases loading time of your catalog grid page. Bcoz in this render function, array creates for every products every time.

Answer (score 1):

**The above code Works Fine but there is a problem of page load time, this render function increases loading time of your catalog grid page. Bcoz in this render function, array creates for every products every time.**

To Overcome from this problem you need to do some changes in your **render function()** as below:-

```
class ***Company_Module***_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Render_Category
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
  {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getEntityId());
    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $allCats = '';
    foreach($cats as $key => $cat)
    {
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
        $allCats.= $_category->getName();
        if($key < count($cats)-1)
            $allCats.= ',<br />';
    }
    return $allCats;
  }
}
```